# vue vuelidate required fields from server

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

I get the list of the required fields from the server and want to move the list into the validations function.

```
data() {
    return {
      fieldsFromServer: {},
      requiredFields: {},
    }
  },
```

```
created() {
  dataAPI.getFormData()
    .then(response => {
        this.fieldsFromServer = response.data;
    })
},
```

```
watch: {
    fieldsFromServer() {
      this.fieldsFromServer.forEach(field => {
         this.requiredFields[field.name] = {required}
      })
    }
  },
```

```
  validations() {
    return {
      fieldsData: this.requiredFields
    }
  },
```

but validations() has an empty object. I want to have here an object with fields and rules (I fill it in watch()). Can I use in validations() the fields from the server?

Comment: See https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-dynamic-validation-schema . The obvious way is to lift the request one way higher and don't render this component until data is ready to use

Answer (score 0):

I changed validations() and it works

```
  validations() {
    return {
      fieldsData: {...this.requiredFields}
    }
  },
```